# Create Azure Website from command line, PowerShell

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm looking into the possibilities of hosting several websites in Windows Azure.

Right now, I have a dedicated server where I have developed a Windows Service which performs the following tasks every 5 minutes:

- Looks at a table in a database
- Finds new sites Creates the site in IIS
- Creates the database on the SQL server
- Deploys an MVC 3 package to IIS with parameters for connection strings and such

In Azure, I can't find a way to create a Website from PowerShell looking at the Cmdlets docs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj152841.aspx

What looks strange, is that using the command line tools for Mac and Linux you can create new sites: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/other-resources/command-line-tools/#Commands_to_manage_your_web_sites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's right, there is no PowerShell support for WAWS at the moment. Here is the answer from Microsoft on the WAWS forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/windowsazurewebsitespreview/thread/f4e69962-a1ec-437f-b205-bb1664242ed2

Comment: That was the answer i feared :)

Comment: Note that you could reverse engineer the Linux CLI: https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/lib/cli/commands/site.js

Answer (score 0):

You can install the cross platform tools on Windows. First [install Node.js](http://nodejs.org/#download) then run  `npm install azure -g`.

You then have access to Windows Azure Web Sites tools. You can watch me demo the tools on [this episode of WebCampsTV](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/Cory-Fowler-Joins-Webcamps-TV-and-Introduces-the-Node-js-CLI-Tools)